Linearity of and pointwise equality in expectation of min() function
Consider the expressions $f = c + s*E[min(a/s, X)]$ and $g = E[min(c + a, c+sX)]$ where

c >= 0
0 < s <= 1
a >= 0
X ~ Poisson($\lambda$/s)

I'd like to think that $f = g$, reasoning as follows by linearity of expectation and pointwise equality of min function:
$c+s*E[min(a/s, X)] = c+E[s*min(a/s, X)] = c+E[min(a, sX)] = E[c+min(a, sX)] = E[min(c+a, c+sX)]$.
However, when programming $f$ and $g$ I get results that often differs by a couple of decimals and sometimes even by 1. So I wonder if I have made some mathematical thinking error in my above derivation.
My uncertainty in what it might be stems from the fact that when I instead compare $c + E[min(a, X)]$ to $E[c + a, c + X]$ the results agree up to 3 decimals which I can much easier see being rounding errors and the like.

The math looks correct, so consider focusing on the programming errors.  One could speculate about many reasons, ranging from loss of floating point precision (which seems unlikely) through all possible kinds of bugs.
